# Question on $\sum_{p\leq x}f(p)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In the paper of J. Barkley Rosser and Lowell Schoenfeld http://www.seanerikoconnor.freeservers.com/Mathematics/AbstractAlgebra/PrimitivePolynomials/Approximate_Formulas_for_Some_Functions_of_Prime_Numbers.pdf page 68, they obtained the following formula
[image]

My question is : should we assume that the integral 2.28 is convergent or this integral is convergent by proof?

Comment: convergence certainly depends on $f$

Answer (score 1):

Your screen-shot cut off half of the explicit answer to your question (emphasis by me):

> **If** the integral in (2.28) below con-
>
> verges, we can rewrite (2.26) as

Comment: What  does means that if the integral not converge? Is  the approximation of the sum above false?